# Reference a DSL from another DSl and its model

Tags: xtext

Due to the discussion a working example was created and added to https://github.com/Johanvdberg/mcrl2.xtext, see the test.multiname.* and test.reflang.* eclipse projects.

*Multiname* is defined by the grammar

```
grammar test.multiname.dsl.MultiNameDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate multiNameDsl "http://www.multiname.test/dsl/MultiNameDsl"

Model:
    modules+=Module+;

Module:
    'begin module' name=ID
    vars+=Vars*
    funcs+=Funcs*
    'end_module';

VarName:
    name=ID;

FuncName:
    name=ID;

Name:
    VarName | FuncName;

Funcs:
    'func' left=FuncName (bracket?='(' ')')? '=' right=[Name] ';';

Vars:
    'var' VarName ';';
```

Files with this grammar will look like

```
begin module test1
var t1v1;
var t1v2;
end_module
```

or

```
begin module test2
var t2v1;
var t2v2;
end_module
```

The grammar of the language that will reference the above language, *RefLang*

grammar test.reflang.dsl.RefDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

```
generate refDsl "http://www.reflang.test/dsl/RefDsl"
import "http://www.multiname.test/dsl/MultiNameDsl" as multi

Model:
    ref_from=Import
    refs=DataRef;

Import:
    'import' imports=[multi::Module];

DataRef:
    'ref_vars' data+=[multi::VarName|FQN] (',' data+=[multi::VarName|FQN])*;

FQN:
    ID ("." ID)*;
```

and a file with the above grammar looks like:

```
import test2
ref_vars test2.t2v1, test1.t1v1
```

The desire behavior is that `ref_vars` can only be from the modules specified with `import`, in the above file that is `test2` and var `test1.t1v1` is not correct.

The scope provider for *RefLang* is:

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof DataRef) {
        if (reference == RefDslPackage.Literals.DATA_REF__DATA) {
            val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context)
            return super.getScope(context, reference);
        }
    }
    return super.getScope(context, reference);
}
```

But I cannot access the model element `test2` defined in the *multiname* language and reference from the *RefLang* by using rootElement. All the attributes `rootElement.ref_from.imports.{vars, funcs}` are `null`.

**Note** the questioned changed a bit and thew working, these changes was made based on comment on the old question.

**Old question**
I have two grammars `A` and `B` where grammar `B` reference elements from the grammar `A`:

```
Model:
    import_model=Import
    flows=FlowData;

Import :
    'import' importURI=STRING ';';


FlowData:
    'flows' data+=[A::Flow|FQN] (',' data+=[A::Flow|FQN])* ';';

FQN: ID ("." ID)*;
```

`importURI` define the file that use grammar `A` and contain the definition of `Flow` begin referenced.

Using context menu as in https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/ the model of grammar `B` can be accessed. How can the model of the file specified by `importURI` be accesses in the same handler?

**Update 1**

Addition to the MWE2 file related to the import:

```
fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment2 auto-inject {}
referencedResource="platform:/resource/.../A.genmodel"
```

in the grammar file

```
import "http://www..../A" as A
```

dependency in grammar B's dsl project plugin.xml to the dsl project of grammar `A`  was added. Dependency of the ide and ui projects to ide and ui was also added, respectively.

The complete model of grammar `A` need to be accessed. Grammar `A` define a system and grammar `B` define where data is in the system and the union of the two model needs to be converted.

More than one configuration (model) may exist for each model of grammar `A`.

Comment: It actually can't (directly) imports are imports only and not a reference. Is it sufficient to simply follow the flow references or do you need to follow unused imports as well ? Did you setup scoping correct to work with the old import Uri syntax? Please elaborate

Comment: please see update 1

Comment: Import Uri is not used if you use imported names based scoping . And still the question: is this about import Uri (data references not working in editor) or is this about following the data references or about loading the unused importUri file somewhere e.g. Inside the handler

Comment: load the importUri in a handler of grammar `B`. The editor part works.

Comment: I doubt that. It will work if you import another non existing file as well.

Comment: And what's the reason to load? Asking the flow data for its datas is not enhough?

Comment: for import uri scoping you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751250/how-to-turn-off-global-scope-in-xtext-2-9/36753567#36753567

or

Comment: or do something like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977296/xtext-multi-file-cros-refference

Comment: If the file imported does not exist, the editor part does not work. I use   Xtext Complete SDK 2.11.0.v20170127-0250  rg.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group Eclipse Xtext. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751250/how-to-turn-off-global-scope-in-xtext-2-9/36753567#36753567 does not work, the variable `importuriglobalscopeprovider` does not exist and there is no import quick fix.

Comment: Can you please file a complete reproducible example

Comment: The import Uri has a different casing. Looking via open type dialog might reveal it

Comment: Major update on the question. It a bit different but will still solve my original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be a guy that really hats assignments in grammars

```
Funcs:
'func' left=FuncName (bracket?='(' ')')? '=' right=[Name] ';';

Vars:
'var' varName=VarName ';';
```

here is the scopeprovider that works fine for me

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (context instanceof DataRef) {
            if (reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.DATA_REF__DATA) {
                val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(context, Model)
                val names = <Name>newArrayList
                val importedModule = rootElement?.ref_from?.imports
                if (importedModule !== null) {
                    for (v : importedModule.vars.map[varName]) {
                        names += v
                    }
                    for (f : importedModule.funcs.map[left]) {
                        names += f
                    }
                }
                // this is the unqualified variant
                // return Scopes.scopeFor(names)
                // this is the unqualified variant
                return Scopes.scopeFor(names, [QualifiedName.create(importedModule.name, it.name)], IScope.NULLSCOPE)
            }
        }
        return super.getScope(context, reference);
    }

}
```

furthermore the usage of spaces in keywords is code smell and might lead to unexpected behaviour

and you should consider simple sames only for the references
(in scoping - see my comment - and in grammar `ref=[XXX|ID]`

Comment: The space was a typo, the space should have been `_`.  What does the `?` marks do in `rootElement?.ref_from?.imports` after the statement is executed the previous `null` fields are populated.

Comment: ?. is just a null safety

x?.y.?.z gives null if x is null or y is null or z is null but no NullPointerException